# Lucee isDate evaluation not working correctly

Tags: cfml, railo, lucee

Lucee isDate evaluation is not working correctly look at the following code snippet and the attached screenshot of the resulting dump.

But coldfusion working properly

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfdump var="#dateformat('02 66795860','yyyy-mm-dd')#" />
    <cfdump var="#isDate('02 66795860')#" />
</cfoutput>
```

[image]

Comment: This was raised as a bug before and rejected, see https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-1185

Comment: If you want to compare date parsing and differences between isDate(), DateTimeParse() and LSDateTimeParse(), check out this blog post that compares RSS date parsing using Moment.js and CFML. I didn't compare Lucee, but it had more issues than Adobe ColdFusion. https://gamesover2600.tumblr.com/post/162824791674/date-parsing-momentjs-vs-coldfusion-2016  (NOTE: I used CommandBox to generate and compare ACF & Lucee results.)